# Do the pivot columns of a matrix in reduced row echelon form form a basis for the column space of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In the lecture notes I'm working through, it says that for a matrix A, the pivot columns of the matrix in reduced row echelon form are a basis for the column space of A. I've also seen some 'proofs' on the internet that support this.

But this doesn't seem correct: take for example 
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 4 \\
    2 & 1 & 4 \\
    2 & 1 & 4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then in reduced row echelon form this is :$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0.5 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and the pivot column is$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

But there's no way to write one of the columns of the original matrix say

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\
    1 \\
    1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
 as a linear combination of the pivot column.

Comment: The rows form a basis for the row space though. As you can see it's not true that the pivot columns form a basis for the column space unless you do column reduction.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1044230/265466.

Answer (score 2):

When you do row reduction, you are constructing a basis of the row space by eliminating dependent rows and ending up with a linearly independent set. It has little relation to the column space, and as you can see the columns do not necessarily form a basis for the column space. However, the column space has the same dimension as the space spanned by the pivot columns, so it is related by a change of basis.

The change of basis is described by the row operations that you perform, so it's not exactly arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Your lecture notes are wrong (or you’re misinterpreting them). The correct statement is that the columns of the *original* matrix that correspond to pivot columns in the RREF are a basis for the column space.